# Cron job setup in specific time

Tags: cron, cpanel

I am using shared hosting cpanel my server timezone UTC format.
Every minute cron job is working fine.
Minute Hour Day Month Weekday   Command
*      *    *   *     *

But when I am trying to Once per day it's not working.
15  21  *   *   *

in the above settings, it should run at 09:15 pm but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

verify **your local timezone** and **server timezone** are same or different.

in cronjob set the time by server timezone....

may be